# Jquery Mobile selectmenu - How to extend widget to add a <span> to the enhanced html

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

In an jquery mobile application i want to edit the enhanced html of select element for the following purpose

[image: BAScic]

to

[image: Enhanced]

For this i have edited the jquery mobile base file.

```
    setButtonText: function() {
    var self = this,
        selected = this.selected(),
        text = this.placeholder,
        phText = this.title,
        span = $( document.createElement( "span" ) );
        spanNew = $( document.createElement( "span" ) );




this.button.children( "span" ).not( ".ui-li-count, .pc" ).remove().end().end().prepend( (function() {
        if ( selected.length ) {
            text = selected.map(function() {
                return $( this ).text();
            }).get().join( ", " );
        } else {
            text = self.placeholder;
        }

        if ( text ) {
            span.text( text );
        } else {

            // Set the contents to &nbsp; which we write as &#160; to be XHTML compliant - see gh-6699
            span.html( "&#160;" );
        }

        // TODO possibly aggregate multiple select option classes
        return span
            .addClass("sb")
            .addClass( self.select.attr( "class" ) )
            .addClass( selected.attr( "class" ) )
            .removeClass( "ui-screen-hidden" );
    })()); 
    var selVal = selected.map(function() {
                return $( this ).val();
            }).get().join( ", " );

    // to add additional span i have included the following code   

    if ( selected.length && selVal != "") {
        this.button.children( "span" ).not( ".ui-li-count, .sb" ).remove().end().end().prepend( (function() {   

            spanNew.html(self.select.attr('title'));
            // TODO possibly aggregate multiple select option classes
            return spanNew
                .addClass("pc") 
                .addClass( self.select.attr( "class" ) )
                .addClass( selected.attr( "class" ) )
                .removeClass( "ui-screen-hidden" );
        })());  
    }else{
        this.button.children( ".pc" ).remove();
    }


},
```

I know its not good to edit the base file. So anybody can help me to move this logic out of  the jquery mobile base file.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it updating the content of the element `your_select-button` (JQuery Mobile appends `-button` to the ID of your select widget):

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <select id="your_select" data-native-menu="false" data-inline="true">
    <option value="1st">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2nd">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3rd">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function UpdateSelect()
{
    var value = $("#your_select").val();
    var html = '<h5 style="margin:0">Selected Option is</h5><h4 style="margin:0">The ' + value + ' option</h4>';
    $("#your_select-button").html(html);
}

$(document).on("pageshow","#page", function()
{
    UpdateSelect();

    $(document).on("change", "#your_select", function()
    {
        UpdateSelect();
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz67p4o2/)**

Comment: using Jquery mobile  version 1.4.5

Comment: that works also with version 1.4.5 (JSFiddle doesn't support that yet)

Comment: i cannot see a element  "select-button"

Comment: it's created by JQM when enhancing a select: `<a href="#" role="button" id="select-button" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow">`. But the ID **depends on your select ID** (see my edit)